# Документация к структуре tcphdr

Tags: linux, c, сеть, tcp-ip

Где можно достать документацию по структуре tcphdr с описанием назначения полей (интересует source и dest) и с примерами использования? На люникс очень плохая документация, в лучшем случае отсылают к определению в .h-файле.

Пример заполнения полей из кода:

```
//TCP Header
tcph->source = htons (1234);
tcph->dest = htons (80);
```

Это как будто порты, но судя по книгам, в таким полях должен быть IP отправителя и получателя.

Comment: А откуда в заголовке TCP возьмутся IP адреса ? Там только порты и есть. IP адреса в IP заголовке, который в пакете идет перед TCP загловком